# Geometric interpretation of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$-gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, d-modules, gerbes

Let $X$ be a (nice enough, e.g. smooth etc.) variety over the complex numbers, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a gerbe on $X$. Then $\mathcal{G}$ is classified by a cohomology class in $\alpha \in H^2(X, \mathcal{O}^{\times}_X)$, and if this class happens to be torsion then the gerbe has a nice geometric interpretation. Namely, it corresponds to a Brauer-Severi variety

$$\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) \longrightarrow X,$$

where $\mathcal{E}$ is an $\alpha$-twisted locally free sheaf. One can recover $\mathcal{G}$ as the gerbe of trivializations of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$.

Now suppose we have a $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$-gerbe $\mathcal{G}'$ on $X$. For example, $\mathcal{G}'$ could be $\mathcal{L}^c$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle and $c \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$. Can we construct from $\mathcal{G}'$ a space $Y$ with some structure over $X$ in such a way that $\mathcal{G}'$ can be recovered from $Y$? For example, perhaps some choices of $\mathcal{G}'$ arise as gerbes of trivializations compatible with a given flat connection on a Brauer-Severi variety, or something like that.

Comment: From my pov it's the opposite: gerbes *are* already geometric objects, and *they* give geometric interpretations to other things, e.g., classes in $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$, lifting obstructions, odd family indices of differential operators, B-fields in string theory, twistings of K-theory,...

Comment: At least in the smooth setting, I do not see this torsion condition you mention. *Every* class in $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X^\times)$ induces a geometric object like a *bundle gerbe*, or *principal 2-bundle* (a bundle whose total space is a Lie groupoid), or *central extension of Lie groupoids*, and each of these objects has a gerbe of local trivializations with the given class.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf this is the Serre–Grothendieck theorem in the topological/smooth setting (over anything homotopy equiv to a finite CW complex): every torsion class is the DD class of a lifting bundle gerbe for a •finite rank• projective bundle. This Brauer–Severi variety is the analogue of the projective bundle. We can do the non-torsion case in the topological/smooth setting because we can do inf-dim. $PU(\mathcal{H})$-bundles and their lifting gerbes. But I agree: the gerbe should itself is geometric object, assuming it is algebraic as a stack, hence representable by groupoid scheme

Comment: If $X$ is smooth over the complex numbers, then the Brauer group is automatically torsion. Indeed, by regularity we have an exact sequence $0 \to \mathbf{G}_m \to j_\ast \mathbf{G}_{m/\eta} \to \underline{\text{Div}} \to 0$, and a spectral sequence argument shows that the $H^2(X,\mathbf{G}_m)$ must inject into the Brauer group of the function field which is torsion.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I agree that a gerbe is already a geometric object. Maybe my question could have been better phrased as "do analogues of Brauer-Severi varieties exist for $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$-gerbes"?

Comment: @BenLim This is good to know!